# R: if_else, ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement

Am new to R and getting to it after a long time as well.
I got the NFL week 1 data from the site and trying to execute a small ifelse and it doesn't work.
I want the team name in the result field

```
#this works only when condition is true and doesn't when condition is false
wk1$tm_won= if_else(wk1$home_score < wk1$away_score, wk1$away_team, wk1$home_team)  

#this doesn't work - gives me the difference
wk1$tm_won1 <- ifelse(wk1$home_score < wk1$away_score, wk1$away_team, wk1$home_team)

#this doesn't work - gives me difference and not the team name
wk1 %>%
    mutate(tm_won2 = ifelse (home_score < away_score, away_team,
                     ifelse (home_score > away_score, home_team, NA)))
#this doesn't work 
wk1 %>%
    mutate(tm_won = case_when(
        home_score < away_score ~ away_team,
        home_score > away_score ~ home_team,
        TRUE ~ a ))# DRAW
```

My result dataset:

```
season  week    home_team   away_team   home_score  away_score  tm_won  tm_won1 tm_won2
2019    1   CHI GB  3   10  GB  7   7
2019    1   CAR LA  27  30  LA  11  11
2019    1   PHI WAS 32  27  <NA>    14  14
2019    1   NYJ BUF 16  17  BUF 3   3
2019    1   MIN ATL 28  12  <NA>    9   9
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "doesn't work" means here?

Comment: What looks like strings in your data are likely factors. Read your data as strings, or convert the factors to strings. Your code will work then.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that your teams are actually `factors` (which under the hood are just `integer` vectors) instead of `characters`. If the columns are `characters`, essentially all of your solutions work as expected. The reason the output is different is because `dplyr` tries to be clever about factors and keep them human-readable when it can.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

wk1 <- read.table(text = 'season  week    home_team   away_team   home_score  away_score  tm_won  tm_won1 tm_won2
                  2019    1   CHI GB  3   10  GB  7   7
                  2019    1   CAR LA  27  30  LA  11  11
                  2019    1   PHI WAS 32  27  <NA>    14  14
                  2019    1   NYJ BUF 16  17  BUF 3   3
                  2019    1   MIN ATL 28  12  <NA>    9   9', header = T, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

if_else(wk1$home_score < wk1$away_score, wk1$away_team, wk1$home_team)  
#> [1] "GB"  "LA"  "PHI" "BUF" "MIN"

ifelse(wk1$home_score < wk1$away_score, wk1$away_team, wk1$home_team)
#> [1] "GB"  "LA"  "PHI" "BUF" "MIN"

wk1 <- read.table(text = 'season  week    home_team   away_team   home_score  away_score  tm_won  tm_won1 tm_won2
                  2019    1   CHI GB  3   10  GB  7   7
                  2019    1   CAR LA  27  30  LA  11  11
                  2019    1   PHI WAS 32  27  <NA>    14  14
                  2019    1   NYJ BUF 16  17  BUF 3   3
                  2019    1   MIN ATL 28  12  <NA>    9   9', header = T)

if_else(wk1$home_score < wk1$away_score, wk1$away_team, wk1$home_team)  
#> Warning in `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = structure(c(5L, 3L), .Label =
#> c("CAR", : invalid factor level, NA generated
#> [1] GB   LA   <NA> BUF  <NA>
#> Levels: ATL BUF GB LA WAS

ifelse(wk1$home_score < wk1$away_score, wk1$away_team, wk1$home_team)
#> [1] 3 4 5 2 3
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `as.character` in the `if_else`

```
dplyr::if_else(wk1$home_score < wk1$away_score, 
               as.character(wk1$away_team),
               as.character(wk1$home_team))
```